# How can I get -8 for a single DV?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes

From my rep history today:

-8| 1 hour ago| downvote| Does “Pacific Rim” have references/influences

How is that possible? Usually if it was 4 DVs, it would show that it's 4 (and make it expandable).

My only guess is that someone reversed their upvote, and the system has a bug where instead of 1 DV and 1 un-upvote, it just printed the total and marked it as a DV.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like events under days that are expanded when the page loads lack the detail arrows for individual posts; those that load closed do contain the arrows when expanded.

The bottom row here (+40) should say 4 events and expand;

[image: Bug]

Like this

[image: Nobug]

This seems somewhat intermittent. For instance, [my SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900873/kevin?tab=reputation) exhibits the bug, but [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation) does not. On scifi, [my profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3267/kevin?tab=reputation) looks fine but [DVK's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk?tab=reputation) shows the bug. I could not repro on several other sites, but on MSO it seems to happen every time..

Comment: Huh, I never noticed that before..  But to _me_, neither yours nor DVK's expands within the past 2 days.  Probably not a simple per-account bug, if it is a bug and not a design choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/38187/timeline), you got 4 downvotes, which are -2 each - totals to -8.

It shows up in the rep history the same as upvotes, the total for that question/answer for that day.  For example, this:

```
+60     16:38   upvote  How did Hermione catch Rita Skeeter?
```

does not mean you got +60 rep for 1 upvote.

Comment: Today's votes typically have a triangle allowing them to expand into individual vote lines.

Comment: @DVK Wait 2 days, then check again.  I didn't know they could, as I don't look there often, but from Kevin's post it looks like the only ones that are consistently broken out like that are the older-than-2-days ones.